# Is the fishing rod bobber/hook an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is the fishing rod's hook an entity? Can I summon it? Or can I put something like `@e[type=InsertFishingHook'sNameHere]` in a command block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fishing rod bobber is an entity, but it's a bit of a weird one.

As it's never saved to the world (they disappear on relog), it has no id. This means you cannot summon it, nor select it with `type=`.

You can still select it though, with the selector `@e[name=unknown]`, using which you can do anything you could do with a regular entity.

Comment: As a small note, "unknown" is the default display name given to entities without a savegame ID, and is thus dependent on your language setting. For example, in Pirate Speak, the value is "Arr?" (which cannot be targeted since "?" cannot be in target selectors). AFIAK, on servers this would always be US English anyway unless the server is modded.